# Getting a key based on a decimal value closest to a given number

Tags: javascript, object, math

Suppose I have an object like this:

```
var myData = {hex_index: "8d26745060122bf", val_1: 2.003234, val_2: 2.0022008, val_3: 2.0044124, val_4: 2.0045183, val_5: 3.012644, val_6: 1.8760033, val_7: 123.0203457};
```

Given a variable with a given int value, such as:

```
const valueRI = 2;
```

how can you find the value closest to 2 and, instead of returning that value, return the key (ex: 'val_2')?  I have a function that will return the key for an exact match, its the `fins the closest' part that's giving me trouble:

```
const selectRI = () => {
    valueRI = document.getElementById("selectInterval").value;
    console.log(valueRI);
    Object.values(myData).forEach( 
        function(value) { 
            if (value === valueRI) {
                console.log(Object.keys(masterObj).find(key => masterObj[key] === value));
            }
                 
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: `return Object.entries(myData).reduce((a,b)=>typeof b[1] === 'number' && Math.abs(a[1]-2) > Math.abs(b[1]-2) ? b : a, [null,Infinity])[0];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort `Object.entries(masterObj)` by the absolute difference between `valueRI` and the value. Then return the first key.

```js
var myData = {
  hex_index: "8d26745060122bf",
  val_1: 2.003234,
  val_2: 2.0022008,
  val_3: 2.0044124,
  val_4: 2.0045183,
  val_5: 3.012644,
  val_6: 1.8760033,
  val_7: 123.0203457
};

const selectRI = (valueRI) => {
  const sorted = Object.entries(myData).filter(([k, v]) => k.startsWith('val_')).sort(([k1, v1], [k2, v2]) =>
    Math.abs(valueRI - v1) - Math.abs(valueRI - v2));
  return sorted[0][0];
}

console.log(selectRI(100));
console.log(selectRI(3.1));
```

Comment: These were both great answers but I went with this approach as it integrated into my overall app better.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the object, make note of the values with the smallest distance from the target.

```js
var myData = {
  hex_index: "8d26745060122bf",
  val_1: 2.003234,
  val_2: 2.0022008,
  val_3: 2.0044124,
  val_4: 2.0045183,
  val_5: 3.012644,
  val_6: 1.8760033,
  val_7: 123.0203457
};

const valueRI = 2;

// first calculate the distance of each value from the target
// set a variable that houses the smallest distance found so far
// and the key of the smallest distance found so far

let smallestDistance = true
let smallestKey = null

Object.keys(myData).forEach(key => {
  let distance = Math.abs(valueRI - myData[key])

  if (distance <= smallestDistance) {
    smallestDistance = distance
    smallestKey = key
  }
})

console.log(`The key with the smallest distance was ${smallestKey}, it was ${smallestDistance} away from ${valueRI}`)
```